# Remove the text in a shiny::textInput field on mouse click event

Tags: r, shiny, onclick, mouseevent, shinyjs

I have a simple textInput:

`textInput(inputId = "input1", h4("Name"), value = "Your name")`

How can I set an onclick event so that the text completely disappears when the user clicks on the text field? Is this possible via `shinyjs::onclick`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `placeholder` option in `textInput`

```
textInput(inputId =  "input1", label = h4("Name"), placeholder = "Please provide your name...")
```